# Convert child parent data frame to Newick format

Tags: tree

I have a data frame with each row representing a tree path and each cell is a node. The first column is the root node at which all the paths begin.

How do I convert this to Newick format?

[image: The data frame I am working on]

Comment: Welcome! In order to make it easier for people to help you, please mention what languages and frameworks you are working with in your question, and add some tags: https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging